# Java Generic WildCard List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>()

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have question about Java Generic WildCard

**Why this code is not working?**

If B extends A,

"? extends A" means that A and B is allowed for "?" 
"? supers B" means that B and A is allowed for "?".

Am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please provide code as text. Screeshots of code are not welcome on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Its because it is said that list hold some type X that extends Animal. Notice that **it is not anything that is animali** but rather **something, but one thing that is animal**. So you know for sure that there are only instances of X animals in the list. Since you don't know what that X is, you cannot add any animals to the list as it might not be an X.